# Strange CSV file when export "orders"

Tags: orders, csv, export, importexport

When my customers exports a CSV file of the current orders, the export seems very strange.
Here is a image that shows the layout of the CSV file: [image: CSV file.]
Any ideas what the problem could be?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be because MS Office is using semicolon column separators for CSV format as default. Try changing it to **commas**, or use OpenOffice - it allows to choose which column separators to use before opening the document.

Comment: Hi Dimitry, I tried this but it doesn't seem to work :(..

Comment: Hi David. Only now I've managed to examine the screenshot - it looks a bit strange. It seems like there is used some extension which alters orders grid view, and adds href elements with "myparcel-consignment-*" classes. But anyway, line 33 of the screenshot shows that semicolons used as delimiters for inline CSS are treated as column delimiters in Excel. Which software have you tried for opening this document except MS Excel?